# Test SKIPPED in chrome when running cucumber feature using webdriverio

Tags: typescript, cucumber, webdriver-io

**Cucumber WebDriverIO with Chai assertions and typescript.**

I am trying to convert javascript tests to typescript.

When I am running cucumber tests with webdriverio , I ran into this error '@wdio/cli: [0-0] SKIPPED in chrome'

The feature files were running in javascript but not with typescript.

Am I am missing some configurations here? Please help.

error log:

```
2020-05-12T00:22:18.846Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2020-05-12T00:22:18.849Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2020-05-12T00:22:19.893Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2020-05-12T00:22:19.904Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session
[0-0] 2020-05-12T00:22:19.907Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the ./protocol-stub 
 protocol
 2020-05-12T00:22:23.365Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 0
 2020-05-12T00:22:23.366Z INFO @wdio/cli: [0-0] SKIPPED in chrome - 
 C:\Users\xyz\Documents\WebDriverIO\test\features\Signup.feature
 2020-05-12T00:22:23.366Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

  Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 skipped, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:05

  2020-05-12T00:22:23.367Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
```

package.json

```
cucumberOpts: {
    requireModule: [
        'tsconfig-paths/register',
        () => { require('ts-node').register({ files: true }) },
    ],
    require: ['./test/stepDefinition/*.ts'],        
    backtrace: false,   
    compiler: ['ts:ts-node/register'],      
    requireModule: [],  
    dryRun: false,     
    failFast: false,    
    format: ['pretty'], 
    snippets: true,     
    source: true,       
    profile: [],       
    strict: false,     
    tagExpression: '', 
    timeout: 60000,    
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false, 
},
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "*": ["./*"],            
        "test/*": ["./test/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ],
    "types": [
        "@wdio/sync",
        "node",
        "chai-webdriverio",
        "@wdio/cucumber-framework"
    ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5"
},

"include": ["./test/**/*.ts"],
"exclude": ["./node_modules"]
```

}

my file structure looks something like this.

[image]

Comment: Still facing the same issue.. Any help please?

Comment: FWIW I had this issue when I used a `Scenario Outline` definition in my `.feature` file, without an `examples` section.

Comment: @GotDibbs Thanks, this solved my issue.
What seems odd is that when I was working on it yesterday, I removed the examples but accidentally left the Scenario as Outline, but it worked fine..Upon resuming work today, they had stopped working - most odd.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported at https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/6605 and the solution at https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/6605#issuecomment-821184779 specifically fixed it for me.

```
npm install tsconfig-paths --save-dev
```

Then in wdio.conf.ts:

```
const tsConfig = require("./tsconfig.json");

export const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
    // ...
    autoCompileOpts: {
        autoCompile: true,
        // see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#cli-and-programmatic-options
        // for all available options
        tsNodeOpts: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            project: __dirname + '/tsconfig.json'
        },
        tsConfigPathsOpts: {
            baseUrl: './',
            paths: tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths
        }
    }
    // ...
```